# How to rotate camera around some point?

Tags: c++, opengl, glm

I have screen with dimensions: `800x600`.
The object that I want to rotate around is located at `(400,300, -50)` - center of the screen.
Orthogonal projection:
Near plan - 0.1f, far plane - 1000.0f
left - 0, bottom - 0, right - 800, top - 600

Camera:
position at `(0,0,0)`
look at `(0,0,-50)`
up vector `(0,1,0)`

Now what I'm doing to rotate is calculate the `X` of "look at" using: `0 + width * cos(A)`.
`Y` remains the same (0). 
Z is calculated using: `-50 + width * sin(A)`.

Now the problem that I'm facing is that after some angle the object starts to disappear, and it doesn't rotate around the object. What can be the problem?

Comment: According to your math, your camera will orbit around `0,0,-50` with a radius of `width`. But you are saying the object you wish to orbit is at `400,300,-50`. Correct?

Comment: yes, so in order to fix it, I need to change the look at values? Let's try it

Answer (score 1):

The image of a point A under a rotation around another point B (an affine rotation if B is not the origin of the space) is A', with

```
A' = B + R*(A-B)
```

where R is the matrix of the associated linear rotation.

For example, in dimension 2, say you want to rotate A = (1,0) around B = (1,1) by 90 degrees counter-clockwise. That will yield (2,1). Make a picture if needed. And, if we call R the matrix of the linear counter-clockwise rotation of angle 90 degrees, we have

```
R = (0 -1)
    (1  0)
```

and

```
(1,1) + R*( (1,0) - (1,1) ) = (1,1) + R*(0,-1)
                            = (1,1) + (1,0)
                            = (2,1)
```

Now, the solution to your problem actually depends on your implementation of world and camera geometry. You can either rotate your camera around point B or you can "rotate the world" around the camera by the inverse of the previous rotation (as usual in the "ProjectionMatrix * CameraMatrix * ModelMatrix * positionOfVertex" part of a vertex shader, if it's OpenGL or DirectX you're using).